# SQLAlchemy: One-to-Many Polymorphic Relation like Laravel

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement one-to-many polymorphic relation just like in this Laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

I'm not sure if this is sqlalchemy way of implementing but if there is a different approach, I would appreciate your help.
So far I found many different suggestions and to be honest, I'm totally confused.
If you could provide some examples based on the docs above, I would really appreciate it.

Based on ChatGPT suggestions, I end up implementing something like this but it doesn't work

So I have 3 tables: posts, users and media. 
Media holds records about images and users and posts can have multiple images.

When I try to create a user, I'm getting an error: 
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join condition 'users.id = media.reference_id AND media.reference_type =:reference_type_1' on relationship User.images.`

```
class Media(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'media'

    id = Column(GUID, primary_key=True, index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = Column(String)
    path = Column(String)
    type = Column(String)
    reference_type = Column(String(50))
    reference_id = Column(GUID, index=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': reference_type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'media'
    }

class UserMedia(Media):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user_media'
    }


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(GUID, primary_key=True, index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    password = Column(String)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    is_blocked = Column(Boolean, default=False)
  

    images = relationship('UserMedia',
                          primaryjoin='and_(User.id==UserMedia.reference_id, UserMedia.reference_type=="user")',
                          cascade='all, delete-orphan',
                          backref=backref('user', uselist=False))


class PostMedia(Media):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'post_media'
    }


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(GUID, primary_key=True, index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = Column(String)
    description = Column(Text)
    owner_id = Column(GUID, ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    owner = relationship('User')
    images = relationship('PostMedia',
                          primaryjoin='and_(Post.id==PostMedia.reference_id, PostMedia.reference_type=="post")',
                          cascade='all, delete-orphan',
                          backref=backref('post', uselist=False))
```